# SQL injection not returning expected results

Tags: php, sql, code-injection

I've created a test site in order to learn about SQLi and then protect against it. I may be misunderstanding how it is supposed to behave but at present I'm not getting the results I expect.

The page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>

<h1>SQL Injection Test Site</h1>
<h2>Login Form</h2>

<form action="" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
Password: <input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit"></form>

<?php
$db = mysql_connect(***, ***, ***); 
if(!$db){ 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}else{
    mysql_select_db(***);  
}

if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer_data 
                            WHERE username = '$username' 
                               AND password = '$password'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    //we would now process the login if details matched
    echo "Logged in: " . $result['username'];
    var_dump($result);
}
?>

</body></html>
```

The table in the database:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPaR6.jpg (can't seem to post a pic)

The input:

```
username: admin
password: ' OR '1'='1
```

My expectation is that it would find the admin user and then accept the input from the password field as '1'='1 should evaluate to true. It actually returns the result for the first entry in the table, username JBloggs. This is the bit I don't understand.

Can anyone point out a fault in the code or logic that is causing this behaviour?

Comment: SQL also has operator precedence. Your query essentially becomes `u=u AND p=p OR 1=1`. There the password comparison and the 1=1 are not specifically joined together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current injection generates this code:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    customer_data
WHERE 
    username = 'admin'
AND 
    password = '' OR '1'='1'
```

It gives you all the rows from the table. And you just fetch the 1-st one.

To crack the site, try this:

```
<?php
$username = 'admin';
$password = "' OR username='admin";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_data
WHERE username = '$username'
AND password = '$password'";

print $sql;
```

Prints:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_data
WHERE username = 'admin'
AND password = '' OR username='admin'
```

This selects the necessary row.

Comment: The `1=1` in your latter examples are not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to create a $sql variable to see the request. Like that :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_data 
                        WHERE username = '$username' 
                           AND password = '$password'";
```

And then display a var_dump($sql) that way you'll see the final request.